# I don't understand the notation $\nu_1(x_0)>0$ ...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, notation

I'm reading the following article

Gidas, B.; Ni, Wei Ming; Nirenberg, L. Symmetry and related properties via the maximum principle. Comm. Math. Phys. 68 (1979), no. 3, 209--243.

in which the authors prove a number of results about solution of some PDEs and in particular they state symmetry results through the application of the moving plane method. I don't understand the following notation
$$\nu_1(x_0)>0,\quad x_0\in\partial\Omega,$$
(where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$) which they used at the beginning of the following lemma in the linked picture.

[Lemma 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpW4x.png)

Comment: It's a $u$, not a $\nu$.

Comment: I thought the same thing, maybe it was just a typo. But if you read the first two lines of the proof they use again the same notation and just besides the correct notation for the partial derivative of $u$, so such an error would be very evident. So I'm not 100% convinced

Comment: $\partial \Omega$ means the boundary.